# How to solve multivariable nonlinear equotation systems? [R]

Tags: r, statistics

I have three equotations with 3 unknown variables like this:

[image]

Assume that the following variables are given as parameters: [image]

Desired, not given: [image]

What I want is that when I pass three parameters it should give me the solution of the remaining ones. What's the simpliest way to do this in R?
Because I'm a beginner I would like to have some (short) explanations. :)

Comment: Not 100% sure, I think you may want to look into the `nleqslv` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nleqslv/nleqslv.pdf

Comment: @Laterow: I have already taken a look at that package. But I'm still no able to solve this problem. I'm not sure how to transfer my problem to the available functions of this package.

Comment: Solving for `sigma.eps^2` is a matter of mathematics. In the second equation you can substitute `a` (expression from the third equation). Then you can solve for  `sigma.eps^2`. After that you can calculate `a` and then `b`.

Comment: If you have pass 3 parameters, you have 5 parameters and 3 equations so no unique solution. And are we talking about single numbers or variables in the sense of 'variables in a statistical model"? In the first case, revisit Mathematics 101. In the latter case, you'll need something like `nleqslv`. But you don't provide us with enough information to solve your problem.

Comment: It's the other way around. I pass 5 parameters, there are 3 left and 3 equations, so there is unique solution. And yes, mu is the mean of normal distribution, and sigma the standard deviation of a normal distribution. So sigma is always positive. p is the correlation coefficient (between 0 and 1). I hope these information help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving for `sigma.eps^2` is a matter of mathematics. In the second equation you can substitute `a` (take the expression from the third equation). Then you can solve for `sigma.eps^2`. After that you can calculate `a` and then `b`:

```
sigma.eps2 <- (1-p^2)*sigma2^2 # sigma.eps2 stands for sigma.eps^2
sigma.eps <- sqrt(sigma.eps2)
a <- (sigma.eps / sigma1) * p / sqrt(1-p^2)
b <- mu2 - a*mu1
```

Eventually the second value for `sigma.eps` is relevant. In this case the second value is:

```
sigma.eps <- -sqrt(sigma.eps2)
```

This would also implicate other values for `a` and `b` (to compute in the same way as above).

Comment: If you assume that sigma.eps is always positive (which it should be if it's a standard deviation). Otherwise `sqrt(sigma.eps2)` has 2 solutions. And if p, sigma1, sigma2 etc. are variables, this will return you a set of vectors. OP isn't very clear about the nature of the problem.

Comment: I edited my answer. Eventually OP gives a comment for the rlevance of the second solution.

Comment: Indeed, this would solve my problem. :) 
But I don't unterstand the step after substitution. So what I assume you transformed the third equation to a = (p * sigma.eps) / sigma1 * sqrt(1 - p²). And then you did the substitution: sigma.eps^2 = sigma2^2 - ((p * sigma.eps) / sigma1 * sqrt(1 - p²))^2 * sigma1^2.
And then you suggest to solve it for sigma.eps^2, but there is a sigma.eps on the right side again? Or what you've done?

Comment: In the second equation is `a^2`. So, after the the substitution you have `sigma.eps^2` also on the right hand side. Now you can put this term to the left hand side resulting in `sigma.eps^2*(1+ p^2/(1-p^2)) = sigma2^2`.